# c++ classes: different ways to write a function

Tags: c++, class

what's the difference between the following 3 cases:

**1)** in point.h:

```
class point
{
    int x,y;
    public:
    int getX();
};

int point::getX() {
    return this->x;
}
```

**2)** in point.h:

```
class point
{
    int x,y;
    public:
    int getX()
    {
        return this->x;
    }
};
```

**3)** in point.h:

```
class point
{
    int x,y;
    public:
    int getX();
};
```

int point.cpp:

```
int point::getX() {
    return this->x;
}
```

Note: I read that it's somehow connected to inline but not sure which one of them makes the compiler to treat `int getX()` and `inline int getX()`

Comment: First case is most probably illegal, if that header is included from multiple compilation units

Comment: If you don't make the first definition explicitly `inline` then you will violate ODR when including the header in multiple files. The second version is implicitly inline as the function is defined inside the class. It also objectively looks like trash.

Comment: your getters are all private

Comment: Especially with larger functions, which may be calling other functions in other header files, putting them in the class greatly slows down compilation and code bloats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid this first one:

```
struct point
{
    int x,y;
    int getX();
};

int point::getX() {
    return this->x;
}
```

If multiple source files include `point.h`, you will get multiple definitions of `point::getX`, leading to a violation of the One Definition Rule (and modern linkers will give an error message).

For the second one:

```
struct point
{
    int x,y;
    int getX()
    {
        return this->x;
    }
};
```

This implicitly *inlines* the function. This means that the function definition may be copy-pasted everywhere it is used, instead of resolving a function call. There are a few trade offs here. On one hand, by providing definitions in headers, you can more easily distribute your library. Additionally, in some cases you may see performance improvements due to the locality of the code. On the other hand, you may actually hurt performance due to instruction cache misses (more instructions around == it won't all fit in cache). And the size of your binaries may grow as the inlined function gets copied around.

Another tradeoff is that, should you ever need to change your implementation, all clients must rebuild.

Finally, depending on the sensitivity of the function, you may be revealing trade secrets through your headers (that is, there is absolutely no hiding of your secret sauce) (note: one can always decompile your binary and reverse engineer an implementation, so putting the def in the .cpp file won't stop a determined programmer, but it keeps honest people honest).

The third one, which separates a definition into a .cpp file:

```
// point.h
struct point
{
    int x,y;
    int getX();
};

// point.cpp
int point::getX() {
    return this->x;
}
```

This will cause a function to get exported to your library (at least for gcc. In Windows, you need to be explicit by using `__declspec` directives to import/export). Again, there are tradeoffs here.

Changing the implementation does not require clients to recompile; you can distribute a new library for them to link to instead (the new library is ABI-compatible if you only change the impl details in the .cpp file). However, it is more difficult to distribute your library, as your binaries now need to be built for each platform.

You may see a performance decrease due to the requirement to resolve function pointers into a library for running code. You may also see a performance increase over inlining due to the fact that your code may be friendlier to the instruction cache.

In the end, there is a lot to consider. My recommendation is to go with #3 by default unless you are writing templates. When you want to look at improving performance, you can start to measure what inlining does for you (binary size as well as runtime perf). Of course you may have other information up front that makes approach #2 or #3 better suited for the task (e.g., you have a Point class, and you know that accessing `X` will happen everywhere *and* it's a really small function, so you decide to inline it).

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have two questions left. you told me to stay away from the first code to prevent including the function more than once but why this isn't true for the second method too since the function is still written inside the .h file. Plus won't ifdef help here so I could use the first with no problems?

Comment: Also, you mentioned that the second would probably inline the function, is that true for the first method too?

Comment: @john1998: The language makes an exception to this rule for inlined functions, since we can guarantee that the definition is always the same.

Comment: Across translation units the compiler can only inline code it can see. And it can only see code from header files. Separating declaration and definition but keeping in the header using the `inline` keyword allows the compiler to decide if it wants to inline or not.

Comment: so the code in method 1 is not automatically inlined?

Comment: @john1998: no, you need the `inline` keyword. Microsoft blog has a good article on how they do inlining [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/inlining-decisions-in-visual-studio/) if you want to read more

Comment: @BigTemp: You do need the keyword if you write code like OPs: "If the
definition of a function or variable appears in a translation unit before its first declaration as inline, the
program is ill-formed."

Answer (score 1):

> what's the difference between the following 3 cases

1. The function definition is outside of the class definition. Note that in this example you've defined a non-inline function in a header. Including this header into more than one translation unit violates the One Definition Rule. This is most likely a bug.
2. The function definition is inside of the class definition. In this case, the function is implicitly inline. As such, it is fine to include it into multiple translation units.
3. The function definition is outside of the class definition again. The function is not declared inline. This time the function is defined in a separate translation unit, thereby conforming to the ODR even if the header is included into multiple translation units.

---

> what's the problem if both b.cpp & a.cpp includes my header file

The problem is that then both b.cpp and a.cpp will define a non-inline function. The One Definition Rule says that there must be at most one definition of any inline function. Two is more than one. Therefore doing this violates the ODR  and therefore such program would be ill-formed.

> I'm too much confused why it's an error to write the same function in two different cpp files?

It is an "error" because the rules of the language (explained above) say that it is an "error".

> what if both want to use that function?

Then declare the function in both translation units. Only define the function in one translation unit unless you declare the function inline, in which case define the function in all translation units (where the function is used) instead. Look at the examples 2. and 3. of your question to see how that can be done.

> so the code in method 1 is not automatically inlined?

No. Functions are not automatically declared inline. Function is declared inline only if A. `inline` keyword is used, or if B. it is a non-static member function that is defined within the class definition (or in a case involving `constexpr` that I shall omit here). None of those cases apply to the example 1, therefore it is not an inline function.

Comment: why including the header file twice will causes errors? what's the problem if both b.cpp & a.cpp includes my header file?

Comment: I'm too much confused why it's an error to write the same function in two different cpp files? what if both want to use that function? and why this should every cause an error... the function is written in to separate files...